# how to build Tigase Android messenger

Tags: android, tigase

i have download the source code of this project to Developed it and customize it to my domain

but i can't build it .. any one could guide me how to build it .. thanks i am new at android

this is the source code of the file ..**
every time i want to build it there is errors like missing projects and libraries

i can't handler the issue i am using eclipse

https://projects.tigase.org/projects/tigase-mobilemessenger

Comment: have you installed Tigase .... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently built it using maven. Haven't tried building it with eclipse but it should be straightforward. I built it with latest maven(i.e. version 3.2.3) against Android KitKat(i.e. API version 19) on Windows 8.1 using Java version 1.7.0_60. Here are the steps to do this,

- Install Maven & add %MAVEN_HOME%\bin to your PATH
- Download Android SDK & add the environment variable ANDROID_HOME which should point
  to the directory where you have put the Android SDK.
- Only tricky part is to modify the 3 pom.xml files which are included with the project which have the following section(sorry couldn't figure out how to paste XML properly),

http://pastebin.com/vqpthMAT

You need to change the value inside version tags from 3.6.0 to 3.8.0 in order for the apk to be built successfully.